# how to pass javascript function inside res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

```
//defined in xyz.js
function getRedirectPage(pageName) {
  setTimeout(function(){
              window.location = "/"+pageName;
            },3000);
}
  
//server code
app.get('',function(req,res){
    res.send("<script>getRedirectPage('page1')</script>")
    
});
```

1. how to define function in res.send
2. whenever i run the server it should call the getRedirectPage('page1') it will go to js code. from there it will run after few seconds

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. Use `response.redirect`.

Comment: Are you writing a `single page application` or just rendering `web-pages`?

Answer (score 0):

you should add href method and change it to redirect, see the code below

```js
function getRedirectPage(pageName) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "/" + pageName;
  }, 3000);
}

app.get('',function(req,res){
res.redirect("<script>getRedirectPage('page1')</script>")

});
```

Comment: i defined function code in javascript file, i calling that function inside rees.send()